# Function that stores string including tabs,spaces and new lines in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, function, storage

I wanted to store a string up to n characters including tabs,spaces and new line chars but i can't understand how to get this `'\0'` char only at the end of the string.

```
void takeString(char *c,int n)
{
    int i=0;
    char *result = fgets(c,n,stdin);
    if(result)
    {
        while(c[i] != '\0')
            i++;
        if(c[i]=='\0')
            c[i] = ' ';
    }
    c[n] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: `fgets` already stores a string up until a newline, including any tabs and spaces and the trailing newline characters. There is nothing you need to do.

Comment: @KamilCuk But when i, let's say want to store string like this "e[enter]d" with new line inside it ```fgets()``` won't let me do that cuz it will just stop working.

Comment: @varkus  With `"e[enter]d"`, How should the user signal end of input?  What happens after the `d` to say input is done?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I wanted to make it like if the next line doesn't have any chars and user enters new line then function would stop.

Comment: "then function would stop. " is unclear.  The function already stops and returns with all input.  There is not infinite loop here.

Answer (score 0):

> but i can't understand how to get this '\0' char only at the end of the string.

`if(c[i]=='\0') c[i] = ' ';` causes `c[]` to no longer be a *string* as it lacks a *null character*.

`c[n] = '\0';` has 2 problems.  It does not make `c[]`  a string again as it is not setting the character after the `' '` and 2) it is likely setting a character outside the array pointer to my `c` resulting in *undefined behavior* (UB).

Instead, after `c[i] = ' '`, set the next character to `'\0'`.

It remains unclear why OP wants to append a space character.

```
void takeString(char *c, int n) {
    int i=0;
    //char *result = fgets(c,n,stdin);
    char *result = fgets(c,n-1,stdin); // Leave room to append a ' '
    if(result) {
        while(c[i] != '\0') {
            i++;
        } 
        //if(c[i]=='\0')
        c[i++] = ' ';
        c[i] = '\0';
    }
    // c[n] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: I think i made unclear in the question what are my intensions. Basically i want to store a string up to n with new lines. Let say user inputs smth like this ```"Abc[enter]defg"``` and the n is 6. So my function should insert into array first 5 chars including [enter] and ignore the rest of input.

Comment: @varkus  That what `fgets()` does.  With input `"Abc[enter]defg"`, the 4 character of `'A'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, `'\n'`  and an appended `'\0'` will be saved in `c[]`.  The `"defg"` will be ignored for now and remain in `stdin` for the next input function.  How is `fgets()` not achieving your goal?